# Cannot connect with a particular device to Azure IoT Hub

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

If I use a connection string taken from a particular device in our device list, I cannot connect. With other clients, I have no problems. If I take that device's connection string and change a character in the key, the connection, obviously, fails.

It seems that is trying to connect but cannot do that. I know that other developers in the team tried to connect with this client and succeeded. Maybe they left some kind of connection open? Maybe is the connection still open?

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Previous open connections are not a problem, because a new connection replaces an existing one.

I would double check the connection string, and then try to exclude the possible bugs in the app code, using a tool like [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/azure-cli-iot-ext/iot/device?view=azure-cli-latest#ext-azure-cli-iot-ext-az-iot-device-simulate)